# Strength Training for Running Books - Strength without Mass

Tags: running, strength-training, books, muscle-endurance, long-distance-running

I'm a middle-distance endurance runner (58kg BM) and I'm a fan of physiology books such as Lore Of Running by Tim Noakes and De Castella on Running. Can anybody suggest books related to building lean muscle and muscle endurance (ie. increased strength with minimal mass increase.)?

Comment: What is lean muscle?

Answer (score 1):

2 MUST HAVES as far as gaining strength with minimal muscle mass increase.

1)  [Underground Secrets to Faster Running](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1411657357) by Barry Ross focuses on his success with Allison Felix but is directly applicable to all distance runners.  Used in great programs including [Bill Aris's Fayettville-Manlius](http://espn.go.com/high-school/track-and-xc/video/clip?id=7321575) 6 time NXN Champions.

2)  [Coach Running DVDs](http://store.coachrunning.com/) which touch on EVERYTHING a distance runner needs to be successful.  Steve Magness talks in depth on how to structure weight sessions and aerobic training in order to gain strength without mass.  Jay Dicharry also provides TONS of strength training information.  These are the best DVDs I've watched on running and recommend them highly.  The cover it all and is applicable to all levels and all distances above 400m.

Best lessons I can share... monitor the rest and lift heavy with few sets .  Yes this is counterintuitive to the high reps, low weight programs often suggested. It works! The 2 resources above will provide you with tons more support and information as to why that is correct.  Best of luck.